# Direct Gmail upon clicking on email address

Tags: email, gmail, email-address

Is there any way I can click on an email address on a website somewhere and have a Gmail compose box open up with it? Assuming I'd previously signed into gmail?

Best.

Comment: That should go to superuser.com, unless you're looking for a way to do this programmatically?!

Comment: Fair enough. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: or maybe http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [quick guide](http://bnee.com/2008/09/make-mailto-links-open-in-gmail-in-google-chrome-browser-windows-xp-and-vista/) for setting Google Chrome in Windows to do this. Basically, for your particular browser and OS, you'll need to do a google search for how to get "mailto" links to open in gmail.